# What is the format of the input parameter $real in php function trader_macd()

Tags: php

I can't find example of usage for function **[trader_macd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trader-macd.php)** from PECL extension *[trader](http://pecl.php.net/package/trader)*:

```
trader_macd — Moving Average Convergence/Divergence

array trader_macd ( array $real [, integer $fastPeriod [, 
                    integer $slowPeriod [, integer $signalPeriod ]]] )
```

Also, I have looked into the source code of PECL function [trader_macd.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/trader/tags/release-0.3.0/functions/trader_macd.c?revision=327080&view=markup) and did not found any comments.

So, I need to know what is the format of array of parameter `$real`.

I tried to use:

```
$real = [
    [
       'Date' => 1416312000, // timestamp
       'Open' => 3.739,
       'High' => 3.77,
       'Low' => 3.7233,
       'Close' => 3.76198,
       'Volume' => 9737.732
    ],
    [...]
]
```

Result:

```
array(
    0 => 0,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$real` is an array of close prices.

```
$close = array(12.33,15.21,14.54);
$macd = trader_macd($close,15,30,9);
```

Comment: Another related stackoverflow question is here it helped alot to understand better.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427530/macd-function-returning-incorrect-values